# My question disappeared

Tags: support

I had a question on SO, about the behavior of CORS in a sandboxed frame in IE compared to Chrome. Now, I can't for the life of me find it. Asked some time around summer 2018, revised in October 2018 when I made a clean sample.

It's not in the list of my questions. I can't find it by "user:me iframe" or "user:me sandbox". How come?

Comment: Deleted questions might not be search-indexed.

Comment: I didn't delete it. If a moderator did, would've been nice to let me know.

Comment: Do you remember the title?

Comment: Not precisely. Something along the lines of "Access denied from sandboxed iframe in IE"

Comment: having over 10k reputation you can [use the deleted:1 advanced search operator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270562/165773) to search own deleted posts

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I'm curious. If you go to your (Stack) profile's questions list under "deleted recent questions" and for your profile being https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/219159 - Do you see it? Please ping me back if you're to answer. I may not be in the question (anymore).

Comment: Not anymore. It's been undeleted and upvoted to zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming this this it, your question was identified as a "Dead question" and automatically deleted by the Community user:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025737/msie-11-sandboxed-iframe-cors-is-supported-and-still-a-cross-origin-error

Comment: Given that the question was edited the day before it was deleted, maybe this question was deleted in error.

Comment: The downvote happend on the same day the question was edited. Given that it was > 30 days old, downvoted and without answer, the deletion happened as intended. It's also worth mentioning that without the downvote it would have been deleted in December (> 365 days old).

Comment: Understood. Still, some way to know that would've been nice. Since this is still an issue, I'll reopen and offer a bounty.

Comment: @Seva If we alerted people every time one of their posts was identified as abandoned or dead and automatically deleted by the system due to a lack of interest from the community after a large period of time, we would have a lot of people re-asking questions that obviously aren't of very much interest to the community. That would defeat the purpose of deleting the questions.

Comment: @meagar:  Just wanted to point out that the Roomba list [doesn't explicitly state editing as impactful to its algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).